# Skycons break when calling Forecast.io API with time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm using [Forecast.io API](https://developer.forecast.io) with [Skycons](http://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) for icons in a function that calls the API every *n* seconds.

On the second function call the icon disappears. Interestingly, when setting the icon with hardcoded icon type it works and I'm confused. What am I doing wrong?

My script:

```
var counter = 0;
var skycons = new Skycons({
    "color": "#6c5848"
});

var data;
var apiKey = '6b5c02819a985881e46287c6507a9800';
var lati = 50;
var longi = 25;
var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + lati + ',' + longi + '?callback=?&units=ca';

var callback = function (data) {

    var icon = data.currently.icon;
    var tempC = data.currently.temperature;
    var tempCfeel = data.currently.apparentTemperature;

    // Icon
    skycons.set( 'icon', icon ); // this line doesn't work and breaks the function
    //skycons.set('icon', Skycons.SNOW); // this line works

    // Temperature
    $('#temp').html(tempC.toFixed(1) + ' &deg;C / feels like ' + tempCfeel.toFixed(1) + ' &deg;C');

    counter++;
    $('#counter').html(counter + ' API calls');
};

var fetchForecast = function () {
    $.getJSON(url, callback);
};

fetchForecast();
skycons.play();
setInterval(fetchForecast, 5000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skUq9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var apiKey = '6b5c02819a985881e46287c6507a9800';
    var lati = 50;
    var longi = 25;
    var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + lati + ',' + longi + '?callback=?&units=ca';
    var fetchForecast = function () {
        var counter = 0;
        var skycons = new Skycons({
            "color": "#6c5848"
        });
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

            var icon = data.currently.icon;
            var tempC = data.currently.temperature;
            var tempCfeel = data.currently.apparentTemperature;

            // Icon
            skycons.set( 'icon', icon ); // this line doesn't work
            //skycons.set('icon', Skycons.SNOW); // this line works

            // Temperature
            $('#temp').html(tempC.toFixed(1) + ' &deg;C / feels like ' + tempCfeel.toFixed(1) + ' &deg;C');

            counter++;
            $('#counter').html(counter + ' API calls');


            skycons.play();

        });
    };
    setInterval(function(){


        fetchForecast();

    }, 1000);
```

The counter is busted but check the console, its firing requests every second

Answer (score 0):

When using the string from Forecast.io you have to enclose it in quotes. Where you are using `icon` which substitutes something like `partly-cloudy-night`, when you pass it into sky cons it has to be in quotes. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem i was fix it with set string type of wheater.

```
var icon = String(data.currently.icon);
```